# Remote control Apple TV from MacBook

Tags: appletv, remote-control

I need a program to remote control my (new) Apple TV from my macbook.

I know I can control it from my iPhone using Remote. Does exists a similar software for mac osx?

I want to be able to watch youtube videos in Apple TV, and make searches in youtube using my macbook keyboard.

Answer (score 5):

You can use your Mac as a Bluetooth keyboard for your Apple TV. I.e. type on your Mac's keyboard to have text appear on Apple TV.

For this you need Type2Phone ( http://www.houdah.com/type2Phone/ ) from the Mac App Store.

Full disclosure: I am the developer of Type2Phone.

Comment: This is the best option I've found, but it has problems with multiple languages, and and many other limitations and bugs.   I was so annoyed with Type2Phone I gladly paid for 1Keyboard, but found it had even more problems, and so I came back to Type2Phone.  1Keyboard has a slick web site, but it is more limited in functionality

Answer (score 3):

You could try [AirFlick](http://ericasadun.com/ftp/AirPlay/), which will play/stream files from your Mac to your Apple TV using Airplay. It supports specifying a URL to stream content but I'm not sure if it works with youtube URLs. Worth a try as the app is free.

[Edit] Just confirmed it does work with YouTube URLs but it first downloads the video content (h.264 version) and then streams it to the TV2. So makes it less useful than browsing YouTube on the TV itself.

Answer (score 2):

And more options are becoming available to solve this problem! We just launch two new apps for this:

You can try our **CiderTV for OS X** (get for free in Mac AppStore or at official web page cidertv.com/osx)

This simple app lets you to navigate between Apple TV menus right from your Mac. And in case you lost native remote for your AppleTV, this app can help you to pair without it (see FAQ on site)

One more analougue - **Ezzi Keyboard** (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ezzi-keyboard/id1069314102?mt=12). You can use it as a remote control for your Apple TV (2nd or 3rd generation). And navigate Apple TV menus,rewind and fast-forward favorite movie scenes, browse your iTunes collection, type texts, passwords and logins on your Apple TV from Mac

Any feedback is welcome. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

2 years later I seek the same.. and the solution: http://www.eyalw.com/1keyboard

Enjoy!

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Answer (score 0):

Mocha Keyboard Lite does the trick. It's free, but doesn't support the backspace. If you want that, you need to pay. You can use the Apple TV remote backspace.