# Can I use my Macbook keyboard to control my Apple TV via Bluetooth or otherwise?

Tags: keyboard, appletv

As the title says, and if yes - how can I do this?

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of [Remote control Apple TV from MacBook](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12355/remote-control-apple-tv-from-macbook), though that question is now 8 years old, and a lot has changed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, no. But you can do it from the iPhone.